# multiline textfield doesn't work with != as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I wrote some code for some input text fields that need to be filled in before the playhead advances to frame 2.

This is my code:

```
stop();
var inputText:String; 
var inputText2:String;
var inputText3:String;
var inputText4:String;
var inputText5:String;
var inputText6:String;
var inputText7:String;
var inputText8:String;

go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playBtnClickk);

function playBtnClickk(e:MouseEvent):void {

    inputText = inputTXT.text;
    inputText2 = inputTXT2.text;
    inputText3 = inputTXT3.text;
    inputText4 = inputTXT4.text;
    inputText5 = inputTXT5.text;
    inputText6 = inputTXT6.text;
    inputText7 = inputTXT7.text;
    inputText8 = inputTXT8.text;

    if (inputText !== "", 
        inputText2 !== "", 
        inputText3 !== "",
        inputText4 !== "",
        inputText5 !== "",
        inputText6 !== "",
        inputText7 !== "",
        inputText8 !== "")
        { this.setChildIndex(allevelden, this.numChildren - 1); }
else{
     gotoAndPlay(2);
}}
```

But it doesn't work!

If I don't fill in some text `this.setChildIndex(allevelden, this.numChildren - 1);` - it shows up, but if I fill in all the fields it still shows up and doesn't go to frame 2.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: You should read more about `if` statement syntax.

Comment: @Vesper You could considder to help me instead of giving an anwser what doesn't help me further. It is because of the multiline that it isn't working but I don't know how to fix that

Comment: you have to replace your ',', by && meaning AND or || meaning OR

Comment: @user2852398 Cargo coding ain't get you anywhere. Apparently you are doing exactly that, or else you would know the basics of the language you are trying to code in, including errors in "not equal" comparison operator. I did consider helping you, but you are demanding help, not asking for it.

Comment: Also, asking two exactly same questions isn't a right thing to do. After reading the discussion in your second question's answer, I see that you are really cargo coding. Learn it or... quit, I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking if textfield is empty with multiline doesn''t work as3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176367/checking-if-textfield-is-empty-with-multiline-doesnt-work-as3)