# checking if textfield is empty with multiline doesn''t work as3

Tags: actionscript-3

this is my code:

```
stop();
var inputText:String; 
var inputText2:String;
var inputText3:String;
var inputText4:String;
var inputText5:String;
var inputText6:String;
var inputText7:String;
var inputText8:String;

go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playBtnClickk);

function playBtnClickk(e:MouseEvent):void {

    inputText = inputTXT.text;
    inputText2 = inputTXT2.text;
    inputText3 = inputTXT3.text;
    inputText4 = inputTXT4.text;
    inputText5 = inputTXT5.text;
    inputText6 = inputTXT6.text;
    inputText7 = inputTXT7.text;
    inputText8 = inputTXT8.text;



    if (
        inputText2 !== "", 
        inputText3 !== "",
        inputText4 !== "",
        inputText5 !== "",
        inputText6 !== "",
        inputText7 !== "",
        inputText8 !== "")
        { this.setChildIndex(allevelden, this.numChildren - 1); }
else{
     gotoAndPlay(2);
}}
```

I one field isn't filled in, `this.setChildIndex(allevelden, this.numChildren - 1);` has to shop up, and if everything is filled in it has to go to frame 2.
all the textfields are input textfields and multilines but it doesn't work can someone help me please!!

Comment: what do you get when you trace(inputText) ?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I never saw this syntax of separaring the condition on the if statement with a comma, you should separate your condintions with a double pipe for or, also your check is incorrect, try this:

```
if (
        inputText == "" ||
        inputText2 == "" ||
        inputText3 == "" ||
        inputText4 == "" ||
        inputText5 == "" ||
        inputText6 == "" ||
        inputText7 == "" ||
        inputText8 == "")
        { this.setChildIndex(allevelden, this.numChildren - 1); }
else{
     gotoAndPlay(2);
}}
```

This reads: If **any of your fields is empty** then...

Comment: thanks verry much finally someone who thinks with me instead of against me. thanks!!!!

Comment: sorry I cheered to early, it only checks on the first checkbox now so if I don't fill in the others it goes to frame 2

Comment: I think you forgot to include the first text box in the check. See my revised answer

Comment: no I did that too but it still wouldn't work it goes right to frame 2 if still some fields are not filled in

Comment: || means or but all the fields have to be filled in so I thought I needed to use && but that still doesn't work I just don't get it!

Comment: have you noticed I am using equals (==) instead of different (!=), so it reads: "if any of the fields are empty then". if you use && with == then is "if all fields are empty then"

Comment: I want that all the feelds need to be filled in befor it goes to frame 2 I have tried == with ||, == with &&. != with && and != with || and with the last one it stays on the same frame if some fields are filled in but not all, but if I fill in all the fields it doesn't go to frame 2 so it doesn't do anything........

Comment: My answer has the right logic. I need to check what is on the text fields though... WHat do you get when you: trace(inputText) when its empty?

Comment: if I trace(inputText) when it is empty I get nothing like nothing as in text. I have traced every textfield and filled something in the textfield also and I get everything traced back so it schould work but it doesn't go to frame 2 (I'm using this: inputText != "" || for all the textfields)